# Reference a library in weblogic

Tags: weblogic, ref

I hope someone could help me.
My problem is that I can deploy my EAR file and the same file again as a shared library. Both are called sample.ear.

Now, when I click on the library and scroll down to: Applications that reference this library in the Weblogic console, there will never be any information that it is referenced.

Maybe, someone has a hint how to "connect" / reference this library?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Applications and shared libraries are not linked by their names but by applications' deployment descriptors. First, do not deploy the same ear as an application and a library. Next, update your application deployment descriptor (weblogic.xml or weblogic-application.xml) to reference required shared libraries. Then deploy your shared libraries and at last your application. Details about using a SL from application can be found in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#WLPRG352).

Comment: Thanks, did not know that, solved my problem partly. I got rid of my "shared libraries", I deinstalled them and solved it as you described it.